# Setup Splunk alert if count is zero for any of interface in both servers

Tags: alert, splunk, splunk-query

I wrote a Splunk query to get the results and to generate alerts accordingly.

The query I'm using is

```
index=aws_instance_prod sourcetype="alert_log" host="*" File_Count=0
| stats count by Interface
```

When executing this query I'm getting the count of interface which has File_Count = 0 in any of the host servers.

But I want to generate an alert if the count of any interface is 0 in both hosts.

Please refer below screenshot.
[Sample Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IsDN.jpg)

As per this screenshot we could see that S and Y are interface having count = 2 means both interfaces have 0 count in both hosts.
So I want to raise an alert for these both interfaces.

Similarly if any interface returns count as 2 then raise an alert for that interface.

Answer (score 2):

You can update your search query to something like this,

```
index=aws_instance_prod sourcetype="alert_log" host="*" File_Count=0
| stats count by Interface | where count=2
```

This small check will limit your results to show only results which have `count as 2` which means both interfaces have 0 count in both hosts.

And then you can set an alert on the basis of number of records returned by this query, and can trigger actions based on all results or on per results basis.

Below is the link which can help you to configure an alert
[Splunk Alert link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0REbozaALX0).

Comment: @Navneet Gautam, You can try this and let us know, if it works or you face any issues?